# How do I clear Datatables columnFilter select list?

Tags: datatable

I'm passing a json object into a function that creates a datatable.  I'm using columnFilter to add filters to each column, and I use an array to fill the filter list.

I have a pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y62aY.jpg here showing a good filter.

The problem is if I call the function with a new json, the column filters turn into a big string with the previous filter values in it.  This happens even though I'm setting my array lengths to 0 and the json is empty.

This https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3ndc.jpg pic shows a mash of the previous values in the filter header when the table is reloaded with an empty json.

In a lot of examples online, I see people using this:

```
{ type: "select"}
```

That seems to build the list for them, but it's not working for me.  This method seems to be fine other than when I reload the table.

I'm looking for guidance as to how to clear out these filter selects each time I call this function.

```
function popNoteTable(oJson) {
  //these store the unique values for filtering columns
  var oTitles = [];
  var oLocs = [];
  var oSigned = [];

  if (oJson.M_REC.NOTE.length > 0) {
    oTitles = getUniqueJsonValuesByCol("S_TITLE", oJson.M_REC.NOTE);
    oLocs = getUniqueJsonValuesByCol("S_FACILITY", oJson.M_REC.NOTE);
    oSigned = getUniqueJsonValuesByCol("S_SIGNED_BY", oJson.M_REC.NOTE);
  } else {
    oTitles.length = 0;
    oLocs.length = 0;
    oSigned.length = 0;
  }

  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "bFilter": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "aaData": oJson.M_REC.NOTE,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aoColumns": [
      {"mDataProp": "S_TITLE"},
      {"mDataProp": "S_FACILITY"},
      {"mDataProp": "S_SIGNED_BY"},
      {"mDataProp": "S_SIGN_DT_TM"},
      {"mDataProp": "F_EVENT_ID", "bVisible": false}
    ]
    }).columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
    aoColumns: [
      {type: "select", values: oTitles},
      {type: "select", values: oLocs},
      {type: "select", values: oSigned},
      null,
      null
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out that the filtering functionality must modify my table headers somehow.  If I redefine my table, by calling the following function, before calling the above function to do the datatables piece, everything works fine.

```
function defineTable() {
  var sTable
    = '<table id="example" class="display" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">' +
    ' <thead>' +
    '   <tr>' +
    '     <th>Note Title</th>' +
    '     <th>Facility</th>' +
    '     <th>Signed By</th>' +
    '     <th>Signed Dt/Tm</th>' +
    '     <th>Event Id</th>' +
    '   </tr>' +
    '   <tr>' +
    '     <th>Note Title</th>' +
    '     <th>Facility</th>' +
    '     <th>Signed By</th>' +
    '     <th>Signed Dt/Tm</th>' +
    '     <th>Event Id</th>' +
    '   </tr>' +
    ' </thead>' +
    ' <tbody></tbody>' +
    ' <tfoot>' +
    '   <tr>' +
    '     <th>Note Title</th>' +
    '     <th>Facility</th>' +
    '     <th>Signed By</th>' +
    '     <th>Signed Dt/Tm</th>' +
    '     <th>Event Id</th>' +
    '   </tr>' +
    ' </tfoot>' +
    '</table>';

  $('#notesTable').html(sTable);
}
```